# How to add authentication on Azure Web App using Authentication feature via Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-webapps

I would like to add authentication to a web application running ​on Azure Web Apps using Azure AD B2C.

To do so, I followed the following steps:

1. Create an tenant on Azure AD B2C
2. Add app registration and client key
3. Add user flow
4. From "Authentication" (on the left side panel) on Azure Web Apps, I chose Microsoft as identity provider and supplied configurations based on the values obtained in the previous steps.

But when I accessed the Azure Web Apps url, I was not redirected to the login page, but got the following message.

```json
{"code":401,"message":"An error of type 'unauthorized_client' occurred during the login process: 'AADB2C90057: The provided application is not configured to allow the 'OAuth' Implicit flow.\r\nCorrelation ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\r\nTimestamp: 2021-04-09 10:06:00Z\r\n'"}
```

Also, in the edit page of identify provider, it says `Application with ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx not found in the current tenant. Tenant ID: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy.`

This obviously means that the application I registered on the Azure B2C tenant is not on the same tenant as one the Azure Web Apps is linked.

My question is "how to add authentication on Azure Web App using its "Authentication" feature via Azure AD B2C?".
Does Microsoft identity provider of The "Authentication" feature only support clients on the same tenant as Azure Web Apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how to add authentication on Azure Web App using its "Authentication"
> feature via Azure AD B2C?

According to your error, it should be caused by your application not enabling implicit flow. So, you need to enable it in Azure B2C.

1. Go to Azure B2C portal>App registrations>your app>Authentication.

[image]

2.Go to Azure B2C portal>Applications (Legacy)>your app.

[image]

> Does Microsoft identity provider of The "Authentication" feature only
> support clients on the same tenant as Azure Web Apps?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks it worked! But why do I have to allow implicit flow? Can I use access code grant rather than implict flow?

Comment: @hitochan   Because you may be trying to get the `id token` and `access token` in the browser, this is a feature of implicit flow. Of course, you can also use the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow), which requires you to obtain the authorization code in your browser.

Comment: @hitochan  Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I see, though I don't remember changing the setting to get id token and access token in the browser. Anyways I will do more research by myself.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I confirmed that access_token was enabled... thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Azure App Service**--> Under **Settings** Click **Authentication**
[AppService Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X3Ri.png)

Edit **Authentication Settings** and select **RequiresAuthentiction**
[Authentication allow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8qCH.png)

Then Click on **Add Identity Provider** and Select the Identity provider from the list
[Select Provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXHPs.png)

After Selecting Identity Provider choose **App Registration type**. Microsoft itsef creates and registers App registration for top 2 choices
--> If you choose **Provide the details of an existing app registration** follow below steps

**To create an App Registration in AAD**
follow this link-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#register-an-application-with-azure-ad-and-create-a-service-principal

1.Fill the **Application Client Id** which is **App Registration ID** you will get on creating **App Registration**

2.provide client secret which you can create on App Registration

3.**Issuer url** would be -- **[https://sts.windows.net/{tenant-id}/v2.0](https://sts.windows.net/%7Btenant-id%7D/v2.0)** *(replace with your Tenant ID inside{})*

4.**Allowed token audiences** would be -- **api://{Application-Client-Id}***(replace with your Application Client Id inside{})*
[Authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpO63.png)
and Click **Add**

5.Final task is to add Authentication scope
Goto your **AppRegistration** in AAD and click **Authentication**
[Authentication AAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvOel.png)

6. click on **Add a platform** and select **Web**

7.After selecting add a **Redirect URI**
Redirecting URI would be **https://{appservice-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback** *(replace with your app service name inside{})* and select **ID Tokens**
[Rediret URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2BBp.png)
Click on **configure**